# I got a blank page even after configuring .htaccess file in build of react app on plesk server

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, build, react-router, plesk

It seems everything is good after hosting the build of my react app on my plesk server. I'm using React-router and it works fine while I'm clicking on links, but when I refresh my webpage it returns an apache 404 error.

After adding the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

in my .htaccess file placed on the root of my hosting folder, a got a blank page.

Can anyone please help me ? Am am using "react": "17.0.1" and "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",,
Plesk server version : Plesk Obsidian 18.0.31 Update #3